# What's the name for this very thin metal sanding disk for use in a drill?

Tags: drill, sanding

I have a sanding disc that attaches to my drill, and i'm struggling to find a replacement.
Does anyone know what it's officially called?

- I reckon it's about 180 grit.
- It's about 127mm external diameter (but i'm not bothered as long as its approx the same size)
- Its 14 mm internal diameter, which is more critical.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not meant for use in a 5" angle grinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be referred to as a "Tungsten carbide buffing disc".

Answer (score 1):

I found this page by also trying to find the name of this disc, which I too need to replace for use with my electric drill. I use it with a sanding disc rubber backing pad attachment, whereby I secure the disc to said attachment with a central screw and use it to sand very rough wood, where most paper and/or cloth type sanding discs would tear easily.
I have looked up the 'Tungsten carbide buffing disc' mentioned above and can find none that look like the disc I have been using for years, as they all seem to have a much wider central hole - 22.5mm instead of required 15mm and they are all about 6mm thick instead of being sheet metal.
After searching many alternatives I have finally tracked the correct disc down. It is a Cintride Abrasive Disc and a three disc set (Coarse, Medium & Fine) can be found on **[eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CINTRIDE-TUNGSTEN-CARBIDE-ABRASIVE-SANDING-DISC-SET-SAND-PAPER-RUST-METAL-PLAS-/222512251527)** (y-tools or M A Tooling shop) and I, personally, have ordered some today!
I hope the above is of some help. :-)